# API. Предварительная загрузка файла

Tags: спецификация, json-api

Создано api с использованием спецификации [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/). Но она не предусматривает загрузку файлов. И поэтому было принято решение создавать ресурсы в два этапа:

1. Предварительная загрузка изображений во временную папку без привязки к ресурсу
2. Сохранение ресурса с привязкой ранее загруженного изображения

Есть ли спецификация, описывающий данный метод сохранения? Как очищать временное хранилище от ненужных файлов?

Comment: А я например сначала создаю ресурс, а потом делаю загрузку файла, указывая в параметрах url id ресурса к которому идет загрузка и никакие временные папки не нужны. Но данная схема подразумевает что файл не может быть обязательным

Comment: @Mike хорошая альтернатива. Но с загрузкой файла мб больше проблем, чем с сохранением json данных. Поэтому хочется сначала отправить файл, т.к. он обязателен. А если сохранять его после создания ресурса, то какой сценарий при ошибке загрузки файла? В голову приходит только создание статуса черновика для ресурса, но это дополнительные заморочки

Comment: Хотя, временные папки тоже дополнительные заморочки

Comment: В принципе можно загружать файлы сразу в постоянную дислокацию, заносить в БД и давать им id, который собственно возвращать, что бы его в объект записали. Но может потребоваться тогда поиск файлов на которые нет ссылок и удаление их через какое то время.

Comment: Правда еще надо где то ставить проверки а картинки ли это. И все становится еще интереснее если кроме картинок для каких то объектов в системе нужны какие либо еще файлы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для примера возьмем ресурс `posts` с полем `image`. Видится несколько вариантов:

**1. Временное хранилище**

Сначала загружаем файл во временную папку, а также заносим в бд. Например, в таблицу `temporary_storage` с полями `id`, `type`, `path`, `created_at`. Валидация файла проходит здесь же. Ссылка может быть такой `/posts/upload`. Возвращаем клиенту `id` и `path`.

Далее сохраняем сам ресурс. Перемещаем файл из временного хранилища в постоянное. И удаляем запись с таблицы `temporary_storage`.

При таком подходе можно удалять ненужные файлы, например, созданные более дня назад.

**2. Сначала сохранение ресурса**

Делаем поле `image` необязательным и добавляем поле `status`. Сохраняем ресурс без картинки и ставим статус черновика. Далее загружаем файл, валидируем его. Из-за статуса черновика мы не боимся ошибки загрузки файла.

**3. Постоянное хранилище**

Как предложил @Mike, можно создать отдельный ресурс для файлов, и связыать их с другими ресурсами. Но этот метод нам не совсем подходит из-за дополнительной сложности очистки ненужных файлов и валидации файлов.

**Вывод:** Первый метод кажется более универсальным и масштабируемым. Но второй способ определенно легче. На данном этапе мы склоняемся ко второму варианту.